# Http GET call to API endpoint with complex object from MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, http-get, asp.net-core-webapi

I have to retrieve orders from my API made in NET Core.

The retrieval is made in an action of my MVC controller calling an endpoint of another NET Core APP using GET.

The API endpoint is the following one:

API:

```
[HttpGet("orders/orderSearchParameters")]
    public IActionResult Get(OrderSearchParameters orderSearchParameters)
    {
        var orders = MenuService.GetMenuOrders(new GetMenuOrdersRequest { From = orderSearchParameters.From, To = orderSearchParameters.To, FoodProviderId = orderSearchParameters.FoodProviderId }).Orders;
        return Ok(orders);
    }
```

An action of my Web App MVC controller must call that endpoint, and for that this is the following code:

```
public IActionResult GetOrders(OrderSearchParametersModel orderSearchParameters)
    {
        var uri = string.Format(ApiUri + "menus/orders/");

        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsCompleted)
            {
                var orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrderModel>>(response.Result);
                return Ok(orders);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }            
    }
```

What I can´t find is how can I serialize OrderSearchParametersModel to perform the GET operation with the HttpClient in the MVC controller.

In the attached code I do the GET without the incoming object.

How can I send this object using GET operation with HttpClient?

Comment: If you put all your parameters in the querystring, they will be translated into an OrderSearchParametersModel but they need to match this model properties names.

Comment: With an http GET you can't send an object.  all you can send are query parameters and header strings.  Typically the query info is sent via the query strign as @MichelAmorosa mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @MichelAmorosa. I you want to put that in an aswer I can choose it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put all your parameters in the querystring, they will be translated into an OrderSearchParametersModel but they need to match this model properties names.